# Azure Face API returns diminishing confidence for images of the same person

Tags: azure, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

For our application we are using Azure Face API to build training set for each person. We are using "LargePersonGroup" for our application. We have created "Person" inside group for all user profiles we have. Every time new face is added for a person we "Train" the whole group. This is how we have implemented.

Now the issue is when we call "Identify" to validate an uploaded image with a certain confidence threshold which is 0.95 (95%) in our case system is returning diminishing confidence even for the same user images. Out of 32 test uploads we got

Below 90:  2

90 -  94 : 12

95 - 100 : 18

Is there any way i can improve the results or is it an issue with Azure Face API. I checked with AWS and their results were far better.

Please help.

Comment: How many faces did you have for each Person?

Comment: As Face API supports only 248 faces per person our system will easily achieve it. But concern is on initial stages when count is not much and faces captured are very much identical even then Confidence is not that good. Even tried multiple times results were same even with time gap to have trained properly at backend.

I have tried AWS Rekognition for same image set and results were amazing. All were above 99%. 

So i believe Azure Face API has more to improve at their end in this.

Comment: Did you read my comment?